# Scrapy - Broad crawler for domain collecting

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to build a **Scrapy** crawler for domain collecting.

What I want is to collect websites with '.sk' or '.cz' suffixes.

My idea is to give a list of start urls (1000 `sk` and `cz` urls) and crawler would go to `url` like `www.example.com`, check for links, if these links has the correct suffixes, then yield `Request` objects of these `urls` - basic forms.

So crawler goes to `example.com`, it extracts two links: `https://www.page.cz/about` and `https://www.liss.cz/info/45` and yield two requests with these urls:  `https://www.page.cz` and `https://www.liss.cz`.

I've created a simple spider now but It doesn't find any links and ends.

Do you have any ideas to improve this spider?

```
class doSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "do_crawler"
    start_urls = [
              "https://www.seznam.cz/",
    ]



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extractor = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow='/.cz|.sk/')
        super(doSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_links, meta={})


    def parse_links(self, response):
        for url in self.extractor.extract_links(response):
            # parse and save to db
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_links, meta={})
```

Comment: I don't think it's the right place for code review and code improvement discussions. Maybe try [code review exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrapy?sort=newest&pageSize=15). General suggestions I can give is to have `errbacks` for your broad-crawl requests and check out [broad-crawl tips over official docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html)